# images being replaced when I want the next image just added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function which animates images like a slide show. What I'd like is to just have the images being displayed one after another from left to right.

I can't seem to find where in the code the images is getting replaced.

```
var realoffset = d.offset % d.total;
$(this)
  .html(d.titles[realoffset])
  .attr('action','article:'+(realoffset+1))
  .fadeIn(600);

$(this)
  .siblings('img')
  .attr('src',function(i,attr){
       return attr.replace(
           /.+(\/large\/[a-zA-Z\.-_]+)$/,
           d.locations[realoffset]+'$1'
       )
  })
  .attr('action','article:'+(realoffset+1))
  .fadeIn(600);
```

Comment: could you format this to be more readable?

Comment: I helped him out with that :)

Comment: the $(this).siblings('img').atrr(...) is doing some replacing on img tag

Comment: I'm guessing that's replacing the source with that of the next image.

Comment: I'm loaded with answers, but there's simply not enough context in your posted code example. When is that snippet being called? What does `this` reference? Your `.attr()` call is fine, as it is working with the current attribute of the current image in the loop, but a full example (use jsfiddle) would really help us to see the full picture and answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.attr('src',function(i,attr){
   return attr.replace(
       /.+(\/large\/[a-zA-Z\.-_]+)$/,
       d.locations[realoffset]+'$1'
   )
})
```

This code is replacing the src of the img tag.  You're going to want to be inserting new img tags to show them side by side, not replacing the current tag's src.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know where I can find examples of just using js to read a folder of images and display them

Comment: Javascript can't read a folder, it's run client side not server side.  So, you'll some sort of server side code to create an array of image names that javascript can then access. This can be done on page load, or on request vis ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Did you write that jQuery snippet yourself?** I'm guessing not. Anyway, there are a lot of factors involved in creating a "slideshow" with JavaScript. It sounds like you just need some general knowledge about the subject.

First, let's get your vision straight. Based on your code, you seem to want to fade images into view as they are cycled in the slideshow. For that, study this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6fnx/1/

Now, your code does stuff with `d.titles`; purely by inference I'm guessing that this displays the image and also a caption for the image? For that, study my updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ESP9S/1/

---

There are countless ways to create a slideshow! You can implement auto-play by taking advantage of JavaScript's [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout). You can load your captions from somewhere else. You can get your images from a external script (like Barbara mentioned). You can slide your images instead of fading them by playing with [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It never ends!

Comment: Thanks! VBuck!yeah it's not my code I'm working on a project with a friend and that's his bit. I really just need it you vomit out the images in a grid like structure

Comment: Hmm, well that changes things. I guess I'll have to defer to my original comment. There's not enough information. If I could see the entire source code for this piece I might be able to help you. For example, the HTML + JS + CSS that generates the slideshow, as you have it now.